getting error page not found while giving @login_reequired
views.py
@login_required
def transactions(request):
    user_transactions = Transactions.objects.filter(transaction_medium = request.user)
    return render(request,'transactions.html',{'user_transactions':user_transactions})

urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.signup,name="signup"),
    path('login/',views.login,name="login"),
    path('add_transactions/',views.add_transactions,name="add_transactions"),
    path('transactions/',views.transactions,name="transactions"),

]

error is
Not Found: /accounts/login/
"GET /accounts/login/?next=/transactions/ HTTP/1.1" 404 2846

This is not the root urls.py?

@willeM_VanOnsem nope.

@willeM_VanOnsem urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('',include('cred.urls'))
]

Change the LOGIN_URL setting [Django-doc] to:
# settings

# …

LOGIN_URL = '/login/'
By default, Django assumes that the login URL is located at /accounts/login/, but you can change the setting to work with the paths you defined.

by giving LOGIN_URL = '/login/' in settings.py now it redirect to login page
